# Alternative translation of 'to reply' and 'to answer' which are both often translated as 'répondre'

Tags: vocabulaire

The English verbs 'to reply' and 'to answer' seen both to be often (or usually?) translated as 'répondre'. Are there alternative good translations which help to point out a little bit more the difference which is like 'react to a question' vs. 'give an answer to a question'?

Comment: Not to mention "to respond" ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction between 'to reply' and 'to answer' does not exist in French, as you noticed. Therefore, you'd say:

> J'ai répondu à sa lettre.

> J'ai répondu à la question que m'a posée le professeur.

> Le téléphone sonne, je vais répondre.

or even

> Ils ont essayé de le réanimer mais le coeur ne répondait pas.

Comment: I'm not good at French, but what about "riposter"? Seems to focus on the act of countering (even in battle) and hence may be closer to "reply/respond" rather than "answer" (but then, so is répondre).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Riposter has a rather adversarial undertone. It would fit in the context of a debate or argument, but not really in regular conversation.

Comment: This answer is right but i think you could have pointed out more clearly that the meaning "to answer" is coloquially represented by "répondre à la question".

Comment: @JeremyGrand unless you answer the phone